# iMacro - TIMEOUT_TAG 0 - Not Working

Tags: imacros

I have a script for iMacro and trying to reduce the wait time for tag. Default it 6 seconds and I want to set to 1 second.

Current code:
`var res = iimPlay("CODE:SET TIMEOUT_STEP 0\nSET TIMEOUT_TAG 0\nEVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"#mutual_match_modal>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>UL>LI:nth-of-type(2)>BUTTON\" BUTTON=0");`

But not working. Any help?

Comment: You just missed an exclamation mark in the built-in variable: `SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0` .

Comment: You saved my life (y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Didn't realize I missed the `!` when setting timeouts.

Correct code:
`var res = iimPlay("CODE:SET !TIMEOUT_STEP 0\nSET !TIMEOUT_TAG 0\nEVENT TYPE=CLICK SELECTOR=\"#mutual_match_modal>DIV:nth-of-type(5)>UL>LI:nth-of-type(2)>BUTTON\" BUTTON=0");`

Thanks SO!